# Symfony LDAP, Warning: password_verify() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to connect our Symfony 2 app to the company's LDAP server.

I used http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-ldap-component for the setup.

The problem I have is that the LDAP server returns the fields as arrays (with count key) instead of string values.

> Warning: password_verify() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
>   500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
>
> array('count' => '1', '{ssha}eq3123FwCrDn7OoLOP1234CWnhwzhmOwg543hg==')

I'm not sure if that's the default behavior of LDAP servers to return values with a count key, but Apache Basic Auth works well with this. So is there a way to configure Symfony to work with this too?

```
app_users:
        ldap:
            service: app.ldap
            base_dn: ou=people,dc=company,dc=de
            search_dn: uid=apache-auth,ou=people,dc=company,dc=de
            search_password: -----
            filter: (&(uid={username})(accountActive=TRUE))
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
```

Beyond our company has used different hashing algorithms (md5, sha, ssha) for the password field. Each salt starts with an identifier which defines the used hashing method, like {ssha}.

Not sure if Symfony provides a way to use a dynamic password encoders based on this identifier?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.